# Caddy Server Logs Outputting to Azure Log Analytics

Tags: syslog, azure-log-analytics, rsyslog, caddy, caddyfile

We are running Caddy 2.4.6 in a Linux VMs and are trying to get the logs output into Azure Log Analytics via rsyslog. I have added the facilities for all log levels for syslog, user, local0 through local7. And confirmed this via /etc/rsyslog.d/95-omsagent.conf

So far I have been able to confirm that the logs are going to /var/log/syslog, but have not been able to get these showing in Log Analytics. It should be said that other syslog messages are coming through such as

[image]

Is there something we are missing to get these running into say one of the local0-7 facilities?

Where the Caddy syslog record starts like

```
Feb 15 03:32:31 caddyvm-vm-dev-1 caddy[3158]: {"level":"info","ts":1644895951.5908177,"logger":"http.log.access","msg":"handled request","request":{"remote_addr"
```

And the Caddyfile

```
{
    on_demand_tls {
        ask https://myaskapi.com/CaddyServer/VerifyDomainName
        interval 5s
        burst 5
    }
}

https:// {
    log
    tls {
        on_demand
    }
    reverse_proxy myreverseproxy.com {
        header_up Host {upstream_hostport}
        header_up X-Forwarded-Host {host}
    }
}

:8080 {
    respond "I am alive!" 200
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Glad that you got the solution from [caddy community forum](https://caddy.community/t/caddy-logs-outputting-to-rsyslog-azure-log-analytics/15107/3) supporting the answer provided by forum  posting it here to help the other community members.

As per the [documentation](https://caddyserver.com/docs/running#linux-service) , we need to run the Caddy as Systemd Service. Caddy emits its logs to stdout/stderr, and systemd passes those to the journal.